# How to simplify this: $\left(1-\frac {\sqrt 3-i}2\right)^{24}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How to simplify the following expression using De Moivre's formula:  $\left(1-\frac {\sqrt 3-i}{2}\right)^{24}$?
I have managed to figure out the radius ($r=\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}$).
However, for the angle I get an awful expression.

Comment: You can maybe combine with the binomial theorem.

Comment: If it's worth $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By some twist of fate, you have $$\cos\theta=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}{2}=\frac12\lambda\\\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}=\frac1{2\lambda}>\frac12\lambda$$

So, your angle satisfies $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$, $\sin\theta>\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac14$. But $$\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac12\sin(2\theta)$$ so $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ and $\sin(2\theta)=\frac12=\sin\frac\pi6$. The only possible cases are $\theta=\frac\pi{12}$ and $\theta=\frac5{12}\pi$. But you also want $\sin\theta>\cos\theta$, so necessarily $\theta=\frac5{12}\pi$

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$z = x + yi = 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2} = \dfrac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2} + \dfrac{i}{2},$$
so that
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{\bigg(\dfrac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{7 - 4\sqrt{3}}{4} + \dfrac{1}{4}} = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}},$$
confirming your claim.

For the angle $\theta$, note that
$$\tan\theta = \dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}} = 2 + \sqrt{3},$$
so that
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}(2 + \sqrt{3}) = \dfrac{5\pi}{12}.$$

(I used [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan(2%2Bsqrt(3))).)

Therefore, using De Moivre's Theorem, we obtain
$$\bigg(1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2}\bigg)^{24} = {\bigg(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\bigg)^{24}}\cdot\bigg(\cos(24(5\pi/12)) + i\sin(24(5\pi/12))\bigg)$$ 
$$= {\bigg(2 - \sqrt{3}\bigg)^{12}}\cdot(\cos(10\pi) + i\sin(10\pi)) = \bigg(2 - \sqrt{3}\bigg)^{12} = 3650401 - 2107560\sqrt{3}.$$

(I used [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2-sqrt(3))%5E12) again.)

Comment: This solution works if you either have a calculator or you know that $\tan{\frac{5\pi}{12}}=2+\sqrt{3}$ :(

Comment: You can also use the double angle formula by hand to get that $\tan(2\theta) = -\sqrt{3}/3$, which gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** use the binomial theorem

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^kb^{n-k}$$

for some suitable $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I don't think this is helpful at all.

Comment: It becomes quite easy if you use it together with $a=1$ and $b=\frac{i-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ which both have very easy polar representations. Also the binomial theorem is very valuable to learn for other problems.

Comment: $\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right)^{24}=\sum_{k=0}^{24}\binom{24}{k}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right)^{k}=3650401-2107560\sqrt{3}\approx 1.37$ using wolframalpha

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: that can't be right if $r$ is really equal to $\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}\approx 0.52$, because then $r^{24}$ is tiny.

Comment: $1.37\cdot 10^{-7}$ less than one in a million. you probably missed the "e-7".

Comment: @TonyK Looks like I got the same answer as JoseArnaldoBebitaDris who used De Moivre's Theorem

Comment: Wolfram alpha says e-7 in the answer which means "times 10 raised to -7".

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: yes, but then you left off a factor of $10^{-7}$, like mathreadler said.

Comment: @TonyK You're right. I did miss the $10^{-7}$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the second term. $$\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-i\frac{1}{2}=\cos(-\pi/6)+i\sin(-\pi/6)=e^{-i\pi/6}$$
Now you write your initial expression as $$(1-e^{-i\pi/6})^{24}$$
You can take a factor of $e^{-i\pi/12}$ outside, and you get $$(e^{-i\pi/12})^{24}\left(e^{i\pi/12}-e^{-i\pi/12} \right)^{24}$$
If you use $e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin(x)$ you get the answer using some simple calculations

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\left|\dfrac{\sqrt 3-i}{2}\right|=1$, and that $\arctan\sqrt 3=30^\circ$. So $B=1-\dfrac{\sqrt 3-i}{2}$ looks like this:

[image]

where $|AB|=1$ and $\angle OAB=30^\circ$. By simple geometry, therefore, the argument of $B$ is $\angle AOB=75^\circ$; and so the argument of $B^{24}$ is $1800^\circ=0^\circ$.

So the answer is $r^{24}$, where $r=\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3}$.